# Why this erasure warning with member variables declared as a tuple?

Tags: scala, compiler-warnings, type-erasure

Have a look at this Scala class:

```
class Example {
  val (x, y): (Int, Int) = (1, 2)
}
```

Compiling this results in a warning:

```
Example.scala:2: warning: non variable type-argument Int in type pattern
               (Int, Int) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
    val (x, y): (Int, Int) = (1, 2)
                ^
```

Removing the explicit type annotation gets rid of this warning:

```
class Example {
  val (x, y) = (1, 2)
}
```

Why do I get the warning and why does removing the explicit type annotation get rid of it? As far as I can see nothing really changes, `x` and `y` are still of type `Int` without the type annotation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could rewrite your example to:

```
class Example {
  val Tuple2(x, y): Tuple2[Int, Int] = Tuple2(1, 2)
}
```

This pattern match actually consists of 2 matches - it now says: take the right hand side object of type `Tuple2[Int, Int]` and call the method `unapply[Int, Int]` on the `Tuple2` companion object. The `unapply[Int, Int]` will then verify that the object really has the type `Tuple2`, and its result value will be used to bind values to variables `x` and `y`.

After that, this pattern match contains `: Tuple2[Int, Int]`, so it tries to do an `isInstanceOf[Tuple2[Int, Int]]` check dynamically to see if the object additionally has the type `Tuple2[Int, Int]`. However, generic type information is erased at runtime, so the compiler warns that it cannot actually produce code which verifies that the object is instantiated for type parameters `[Int, Int]`.

In the same way, in the following pattern match:

```
val a: AnyRef = (1, 2)
a match {
  case t2: Tuple[Int, Int] => 
}
```

you would get a similar warning.

Comment: Ok, so if I leave out the type annotation, in the second match it tries to match `Tuple2[_, _]` instead of `Tuple2[Int, Int]` and it doesn't need to check the erased type parameters. So it's an unfortunate side-effect of the special syntax for tuples.

Answer (score 5):

I think the short answer to your question is:

```
class Example {
  val (x: Int, y: Int) = (1, 2)
}
```

because `(Int, Int)` is **not** a type, while `(x: Int, y: Int)` is a valid pattern expression.