# Scala Type Erasure warning in Play Framework Application

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework-2.0

In my Play + Reactive Mongo application, I'm getting Future[Option[Student]] result and I' trying to match result:

```
def getStudent(id: String)=Action {
  val futureOfStudent:Future[Option[Student]] = StudentRepository.getStudentById(id)
  val timeoutFuture = play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise.timeout(0,  Duration(3000, MILLISECONDS))
  Async {
    Future.firstCompletedOf(Seq(futureOfStudent, timeoutFuture)).map { 
      case s: Option[Student] => {s match {case Some(s)=>Ok(Json.toJson(s))
                                               case None => NoContent}}
      case i: Int => InternalServerError("Oooppppps!!!")
    }  
  }
}
```

Everything works like charm but I'm getting ugly warning on `case s: Option[Student] =>`

```
- non-variable type argument model.Student in type pattern 
     Option[modelStudent] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
```

How can I solve this warning?

I googled it and found some articles:

[How do I get around type erasure on Scala? Or, why can't I get the type parameter of my collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramete)

[Why does Scala warn about type erasure in the first case but not the second?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152690/why-does-scala-warn-about-type-erasure-in-the-first-case-but-not-the-second)

but, it did not give me a clue how to solve as part of Play controller.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with type erasure is that you can no longer use type parameters: `Option[Student]` at runtime just looks like `Option[_]`. This leads to problems like:

```
val opt: Option[Student] = Some(myStudent)
opt match {
  case s: Option[String] => println('problem') // this would happen
  case s: Option[Student] => // this wouldn't get called
}
```

The easiest approach to solving your problem would probably be something along the lines of...

```
case s: Option[_] => s match {
  case Some(student: Student) => Ok(Json.toJson(student))
  case _ => NoContent
}
```

but this doesn't really tackle the root of your problem. The `Seq` you create contains a `Future[Option[Student]]` and a `Future[Int]`, so it's likely resolving as a `Seq[Future[Any]]` (the best common type between `Option[Student]` and `Int`), and so your match has to assume that the item is of type `Any`, which essentially removes the usefulness of the type checker here.

You should adjust the `Seq` so that it has a better common type. If you used `Option[Student]` as the return type of your timeout future, it could return `None`, and the `Seq` would be a `Seq[Future[Option[Student]]]`. Then the `map` could assume you are matching on `Option[Student]`.